# How do I find turnips?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the Erebus, where/how do I find turnips? I didn't find this information on the wiki. Do I need to break grass and be lucky, does it actually grow somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no turnips in the Erebus mod...

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer NEI says there is, and the wiki too. They are used for breeding beetles, I think.

Comment: Ah ha, you're right! Well, I'll assume it's in the Erebus biome, and I'll also assume you'll be like *facepalm*

Comment: I have heard that other mods make regular grass drop different seeds, sometimes potatoes, carrots and tomatoes; Erebus probably also drops turnips from grass. If not, then they will probably be in the Erebus dimension.

Answer (score -1):

They can be found in Jungle biomes. The Erebus mod has it's own jungle biome, so I'm guessing it's in there.